# How can i interrupt my function to stop sending data to my angular server

Tags: python, angular

I have my Angular server which plots my Data I get from a python-bokeh Server. On my Frontend, I have a Button which calls my function getData(). This function sends a Message over a Websocket connection to my Python Server. In this message, there is a String which function should be called. When the python server received the message "getData" he collects the Data and sends them to the angular server. But now I want to stop sending data to my angular server(because the Stop Button is pressed).

My Problem: Either I do a while loop to send data the whole time, but then I cant stop the function or I don't use a while loop but then I have to send messages to my python server the whole time with a time delay.

In Python my Code ist something like :

```
while websocketconnection == true:

  imp = getMessage()
  FunctionString == imp['name']

  if(FunctionString == 'getData'):
     *get the Data and send them back to angular*

  if(FunctionString == 'Stop'):
     *close socket connection(not websocket connection)*

  ...(*some more not relevant functions*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend a way I used in the past. You can use multithreading to handle such bahaviour.

Then you either do quick and dirty:
in another thread you assign global value of `websocketconnection` to be False

or
you can create some Event and Signal, so once you trigger button it will perform some logic

PS
in python you can do just:

```
while websocketconnection:
  imp = getMessage()
  ..............
```

Comment: So I should put the while-Loop which sends my data to angular in a thread and when angular send the "stop sending me data" Message, I can kill the thread?

Comment: @SystemmatrixA, you can make a clean exit, killing is not good. For example you have: `while var: do smth`, then when signal comes, you can change the var to False, this will stop the loop and do a clean exit. This one is quite simple to implement